# problem installing Jupyter Notebook on Mac

Tags: command-line, python, macosx

I've literally tried everything and read every previous post about this.

First I tried installing Anaconda, and tried to run Jupiter and it said command not found.

Then I tried

```
pip install Jupyter
```

And I got a long error...

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/parser.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/parser.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/relativedelta.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/relativedelta.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/zoneinfo'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tz.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tz.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/relativedelta.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/relativedelta.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/rrule.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/rrule.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/parser.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/parser.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tzwin.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tzwin.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/rrule.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/rrule.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/easter.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/easter.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/easter.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/easter.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tz.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tz.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tzwin.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b/tzwin.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/nt/88dygr3d4hb7fbh888q3tqyh0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SlCL9b'")]
```

Then I tried

```
pip install --user jupyter
```

which did not throw any errors, but still when I tried to run Jupyter ntoebook I still got

```
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

The other weird thing is that I seem to be completely unable to update python from 2.7 to 3, this is a separate issue which I am not seeking an answer for here, though they are potentially related?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved -- turns out, restarting your computer after installing new software fixes the problem 99% of the time!!